# how can I start again when pressing image?

Tags: python, kivy

How can I start again when pressing image?

I want it to start again when I press the last images or 2/3 second later

```
class MyButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = 's'

    def on_press(self):
        a = (random.randint(1, 1014124315124124))
        if (int(a) % 2 == 0):
            self.source = 's'
        else:
            self.source = 'd' 

class SampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyButton()

SampleApp().run()
```

Comment: What does your current code do, and what (specifically!) would you like it to do differently?

Comment: İts coin flip. when ı press button image it select  randomly image(heads or tails). I want to when it select an image, after 2/3 seconds later or when ı  press the image it start itself again from  button image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Look into kivy's Clock.schedule_once](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html). The basic idea is, when the button is pressed, you will set it to a new image, and schedule another function (let's call it `resetImage`) to run in 2/3 seconds. Then when `resetImage` is called, it sets the button's image back to normal.

You'd want something like `Clock.schedule_once(resetImage, 0.66)`.

Comment: but  after  called program closing. ı want to it start again?

Comment: if the user clicks the button again, it would call Clock.schedule_once again. You want to schedule exactly one event for every time the button is clicked, is my thinking